# Not able to open SQL Sever 2008 Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting the below message when i try and access SQL Config Manager on my Windows Server 2003  R2
    "Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
    Generic failure [0x80041001]"

Also tries with the below solution but still the error persists
    The solution is to go to a command prompt and then run mofcomp.
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared>mofcomp "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Below was the output of the command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"     
Microsoft (R) 32-bit MOF Compiler Version 5.2.3790.1830     
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2001. All rights reserved.       
Parsing MOF file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmp        
roviderxpsp2up.mof      
MOF file has been successfully parsed       
Storing data in the repository...       
An error occurred while opening the namespace for object 1 defined on lines 4 - 7:      
Error Number: 0x80041001, Facility: WMI     
Description: Generic failure        
Compiler returned error 0x80041001      
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Can anyone tell how this problem can be solved?